# Can someone help me solve this?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, homework, linear

A linear circuit is shown in the figure below

[image: Text]

The VCCS (voltage controlled current source) is defined as  1= ⋅ .

The other elements in this circuit have the following values:  1=3.3Ω ,  2=8Ω ,  3=1.8Ω ,  4=1.8Ω ,   =1.5/ , and  1=5 .

(a) Calculate the numerical value of the voltage    in   .

(b) Calculate the numerical value of the voltage    in   .

(c) Calculate the numerical value of the Thevenin equivalent resistance,    in  Ω , as seen from the terminals of   .

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Is this homework? Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: So I've tried using KCL and KVL and making a system of equations to try to figure this out but each time I submit it, it tells me that I'm getting the wrong answer. Do you have any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: For sure. 1. Is this homework? 2. Please show your proposal with equations for the system with KVL and KCL?

Comment: When you wrote KCL, what current did you assume flowed through R2 ?

Comment: Can you clarify what your assumption was ?

Comment: Please show your KCL equations.

Comment: Also, please edit your title to describe the question at all.

Comment: You need to show a significant amount of your own effort. This isn't Chegg.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the issue is that I have no clue how to get started with this question. I'm not doing this for a class, this is a personal study thing

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Hmm. In 2018, "Chegg Services Revenues grew 35% year-over-year to $81.7 million." I could live with that.

Comment: @jonk Yeah, maybe if I got a piece of it. But we are giving away our labor here for free and someone else is "monetizing" it. That makes me feel OK about taking the ethical high ground.

Comment: _”So I've tried using KCL and KVL and making a system of equations to try to figure this out”_ and _”the issue is that I have no clue how to get started with this question”_ are very contradictory. Please show your system of equations or this question will be closed due to insufficient own effort.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework without own solution provided.

Comment: boii we already figured it out. Im gonna do some more self-studying on Thevenin stuff and come back to it.

Answer (score 4):

## Redraw Schematic

At your stage in the game, I recommend that you redraw every schematic. In fact, you should redraw a schematic over and over until it "looks better" to you. There are some general helpful rules (I'll mention them, shortly, in the **Appendix** below.) But they are only a guide. An issue is that you need to develop a sense about things and, over time, to also acquire some standard thinking tools that allow you to more rapidly work out how better to redraw a schematic. Practice plays a huge role in developing those tools. So do not shy away from redrawing schematics. It should become second nature to you.

For example, here's what my mental tools suggested I should draw:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0h62F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Note: In the above schematic, \$V_\text{A}^-=V_\text{OUT}^-\$.)

The above schematic draws your attention to a simple three-resistor divider from the \$+5\:\text{V}\$ rail towards the ground reference. It then adds the current sink, controlled by a voltage, on the right side. On the left side, you can then see the final addition -- the output voltage arrangement.

These things may help you in attempting to correctly write your equations. For example, it is very easy to observe that without the current sink your problem would be quite trivial. But that with its complicating addition, it's really fairly simple as it only draws current out of one node, sinking it to ground. Yes, doing so alters that node's voltage and also the voltage across \$R_3\$, but this clearly isn't rocket science, either.

It's also crystal clear (or should be) that you only need two equations in two unknowns to get started. You will, of course, need a separate approach to produce a Thevenin resistance as seen from the \$V_\text{OUT}\$ pin-pairs. But actually that's just the same two equations but with the addition of one change before solving again. So it's not that bad, really.

Does this help in any way?

## Nodal Analysis (KCL)

You wrote:

> This is a self-learning thing I've been doing over the summer

So I'll try to walk you through the pair of KCL equations that, when solved simultaneously, should provide a starting point for achieving (a) and (b). I'll also add another thought about how to achieve (c).

All of the currents flowing out of a node (left side of the equations below) must equal the currents flowing into a node (right side of the equations below.) Although the method I use for setting up the equations correctly isn't often taught, it is how one of the steps of Spice handles things and I find using the idea helps me avoid uncaught errors when on *automatic pilot*. In short, it just *flows* out, easily. Follow along and see if you understand what I did.

So here it is:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_{\text{A}}^+}{R_1} + \frac{V_{\text{A}}^+}{R_3} + I_1 &= \frac{5\:\text{V}}{R_1} + \frac{V_{\text{A}}^-}{R_3}\\\\
\frac{V_{\text{A}}^-}{R_3} + \frac{V_{\text{A}}^-}{R_4} &= \frac{V_{\text{A}}^+}{R_3} + \frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_4}
\end{align*}$$

Now, you separately know that \$I_1=1.5\:\frac{\text{mA}}{\text{V}}\cdot \left( V_{\text{A}}^+ - V_{\text{A}}^- \right)\$. So the final arrangement is:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_{\text{A}}^+}{R_1} + \frac{V_{\text{A}}^+}{R_3} + 1.5\:\frac{\text{mA}}{\text{V}}\cdot \left( V_{\text{A}}^+ - V_{\text{A}}^- \right) &= \frac{5\:\text{V}}{R_1} + \frac{V_{\text{A}}^-}{R_3}\\\\
\frac{V_{\text{A}}^-}{R_3} + \frac{V_{\text{A}}^-}{R_4} &= \frac{V_{\text{A}}^+}{R_3} + \frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_4}
\end{align*}$$

If you solve those, you'll have both \$V_{\text{A}}^+\$ and \$V_{\text{A}}^-\$. That will answer (a), directly. Separately, since you know \$V_\text{A}^-=V_\text{OUT}^-\$ and, without any current in \$R_2\$, also know that \$V_\text{OUT}^+=5\:\text{V}\$ then you have an answer for (b), too.

To answer (c), all you need to do is short out the \$V_\text{OUT}\$ terminals and find out what current flows in \$R_2\$. If you divide the open-circuit voltage for \$V_\text{OUT}\$ (determined already in (b) above) by the short-circuit current (which is the same as the current in \$R_2\$ as \$R_2\$ is directly in series with the short-circuit, itself), you'll have your resistance in hand, as well. To implement this idea for (c), you will need to modify the above equations to reflect \$R_2\$'s presence and then solve them again. From the newly computed \$V_{\text{A}}^-\$, you can get the current in \$R_2\$.

Keep in mind that you need to modify one of the above two equations in order to incorporate \$R_2\$ and compute the information needed to find the short-circuit current. Suppose \$V_\text{CC}=5\:\text{V}\$, the open-circuit equations solve for \$^\text{OC}V_{\text{A}}^-\$ and \$^\text{OC}V_{\text{A}}^+\$, and the closed-circuit equations solve for \$^\text{SC}V_{\text{A}}^-\$ and \$^\text{SC}V_{\text{A}}^+\$. Then the Thevenin resistance will be:

$$R_\text{TH}=R_2\cdot \frac{V_\text{CC}-\:^\text{OC}V_{\text{A}}^-}{V_\text{CC}-\:^\text{SC}V_{\text{A}}^-}$$

## Appendix

> One of the better ways to try and understand a circuit that at first
> appears to be confusing is to redraw it. There are some rules you can
> follow that will help get a leg-up on learning that process. But there
> are also some added personal skills that gradually develop over time,
> too.
>
> As mentioned at the outset above,
> I first learned these rules in 1980, taking a Tektronix class that was
> offered only to its employees. This class was meant to teach
> electronics drafting to people who were not electronics engineers, but
> instead would be trained sufficiently to help draft schematics for
> their manuals.
>
> The nice thing about the rules is that you don't have to be an expert
> to follow them. And that if you follow them, even blindly almost, that
> the resulting schematics really are easier to figure out.
>
> The rules are:
>
> - Arrange the schematic so that conventional current appears to flow from the top towards the bottom of the schematic sheet. I like to
>   imagine this as a kind of *curtain* (if you prefer a more static
>   concept) or *waterfall* (if you prefer a more dynamic concept) of
>   charges moving from the top edge down to the bottom edge. This is a
>   kind of flow of energy that doesn't do any useful work by itself, but
>   provides the environment for useful work to get done.
> - Arrange the schematic so that signals of interest flow from the left side of the schematic to the right side. Inputs will then
>   generally be on the left, outputs generally will be on the right.
> - Do not "bus" power around. In short, if a lead of a component goes to ground or some other voltage rail, do not use a wire to connect it
>   to other component leads that also go to the same rail/ground.
>   Instead, simply show a node name like "Vcc" and stop. Busing power
>   around on a schematic is almost guaranteed to make the schematic less
>   understandable, not more. (There are times when professionals need to
>   communicate something unique about a voltage rail bus to other
>   professionals. So there are exceptions at times to this rule. But when
>   trying to understand a confusing schematic, the situation isn't that
>   one and such an argument "by professionals, to professionals" still
>   fails here. So just don't do it.) This one takes a moment to grasp
>   fully. There is a strong tendency to want to show all of the wires
>   that are involved in soldering up a circuit. Resist that tendency. The
>   idea here is that wires needed to *make* a circuit can be distracting.
>   And while they may be needed to make the circuit work, they do NOT
>   help you understand the circuit. In fact, they do the exact opposite.
>   So remove such wires and just show connections to the rails and stop.
> - Try to organize the schematic around ***cohesion***. It is almost always possible to "tease apart" a schematic so that there are
>   ***knots*** of components that are tightly connected, each to another, separated then by only a few wires going to other ***knots***. If you
>   can find these, emphasize them by isolating the *knots* and focusing
>   on drawing each one in some meaningful way, first. Don't even think
>   about the whole schematic. Just focus on getting each cohesive section
>   "looking right" by itself. Then add in the spare wiring or few
>   components separating these "natural divisions" in the schematic. This
>   will often tend to almost magically find distinct functions that are
>   easier to understand, which then "communicate" with each other via
>   relatively easier to understand connections between them.
>
> The above rules aren't hard and fast. But if you struggle to follow them,
> you'll find that it does help a lot.
>
> I also tell a bit of a tale and provide some examples of successful drafting
> of schematics [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/308882/38098).

Comment: @John For open circuit, it solves to: $$V_\text{A}^-=V_\text{CC}\cdot \frac{R_4}{1.5\:\frac{\text{mA}}{\text{V}}\cdot R_1\cdot R_3 + R_1 + R_3 + R_4}$$and$$V_\text{A}^+=V_\text{CC}\cdot \frac{R_3+R_4}{1.5\:\frac{\text{mA}}{\text{V}}\cdot R_1\cdot R_3 + R_1 + R_3 + R_4}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111526/discussion-on-answer-by-jonk-can-someone-help-me-solve-this).

Comment: @VoltageSpike Wait? You mean we can't discuss the ***actual*** problem and answer? It's all on topic, no diversions at all.

Comment: So if Va = 0.57, now if we short the circuit, we replace V with 0, or do we ignore it outright? I've never actually had to calculate the Thevenin resistance before so I'm unsure

Comment: @John This is becoming a very different problem. You have a lot of missing background (holes in what you know), I'm growing to think. Have you searched this site for "Thevenin resistance" questions and answers, yet? Or read [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem)? (Read the first bullet point there, which is a quick summary of the idea.)

Comment: @John  If Thevenin's theory is right, then a circuit like yours can be summarized into a voltage source and a series resistance. If you measure the open circuit voltage, that gives you the value for the source. If you short it and measure the current (and you already know the hidden voltage) you can then work out the value of the resistor, too. Makes sense?

Comment: I understand the part about simplifying the series resistance and a voltage source. R1,R3 would be in series and R2 would be parallel to them and then R4 would be in series with that overall resistance?

Comment: @John No. I think you understand a few things. But this one is throwing you a curve and your thinking is still too inflexible to grasp it. I am now, though, pretty convinced that you need to break your brain on this problem. It's probably at just the right difficulty that you need; one to crush your spirit so as to remake you. I think you should stay on target with this one until it finally sinks in.

Comment: @jonk it's actually not the format of the site, the site is a Q&A site. If you need to discuss something then use the chat. The problem is users that want to find an answer have to read through a long discussion, which doesn't help people get answers and takes too much time

Comment: @VoltageSpike Oh, I certainly believe the policy makes sense because it's very easy (and I do it all the time, myself) for a "thread of thought" to divert all over the place. I do think there needs to be a policy and then people (like you) who implement it in order to send that stuff to a dust bin of sorts. But if it were truly intended as a bright line measured only by "number of comments" let's say, then it would be sufficient to write the software to do the job automatically and you wouldn't need the good judgment of a human being and we could eliminate active moderation on that policy.

Comment: @VoltageSpike So I think there is a place for human judgment, more than just saying "too many comments." Because if it is reduced to "policy = N" then it's no longer an intelligent policy designed to clean up clutter and is instead a bright line that even a computer could implement. Just my offered thoughts and not intended to convince you of anything. I'm okay with your decisions. (And is there a way to push all this stuff also into that bin you've created?)