# How to convert breadboard to schematic?

Tags: breadboard, schematic

I am asked to find the schematic diagram of the following breadboard configuration:

[image]

What I understand is that the current flows from R1 to R4, as supplied by the voltage. Since the current seems to split into the two resistors after R1, I assumed that there should be a node. After that, I placed R4 as connected in series with the exit node of the parallel circuits.

Is the following schematic correct?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Yes, though it's probably better to draw it this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frYXbb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

See schematic drawing rules below:

### Redrawing Schematic Appendix

> Rules to live by are:
>
> - Arrange the schematic so that conventional current appears to flow from the top towards the bottom of the schematic sheet. I like to
>   imagine this as a kind of *curtain* (if you prefer a more static
>   concept) or *waterfall* (if you prefer a more dynamic concept) of
>   charges moving from the top edge down to the bottom edge. This is a
>   kind of flow of energy that doesn't do any useful work by itself, but
>   provides the environment for useful work to get done.
> - Arrange the schematic so that signals of interest flow from the left side of the schematic to the right side. Inputs will then
>   generally be on the left, outputs generally will be on the right.
> - Do not "bus" power around. In short, if a lead of a component goes to ground or some other voltage rail, do not use a wire to connect it
>   to other component leads that also go to the same rail/ground.
>   Instead, simply show a node name like "Vcc" and stop. Busing power
>   around on a schematic is almost guaranteed to make the schematic less
>   understandable, not more. (There are times when professionals need to
>   communicate something unique about a voltage rail bus to other
>   professionals. So there are exceptions at times to this rule. But when
>   trying to understand a confusing schematic, the situation isn't that
>   one and such an argument "by professionals, to professionals" still
>   fails here. So just don't do it.) This one takes a moment to grasp
>   fully. There is a strong tendency to want to show all of the wires
>   that are involved in soldering up a circuit. Resist that tendency. The
>   idea here is that wires needed to *make* a circuit can be distracting.
>   And while they may be needed to make the circuit work, they do NOT
>   help you understand the circuit. In fact, they do the exact opposite.
>   So remove such wires and just show connections to the rails and stop.
> - Try to organize the schematic around ***cohesion***. It is almost always possible to "tease apart" a schematic so that there are
>   ***knots*** of components that are tightly connected, each to another, separated then by only a few wires going to other ***knots***. If you
>   can find these, emphasize them by isolating the *knots* and focusing
>   on drawing each one in some meaningful way, first. Don't even think
>   about the whole schematic. Just focus on getting each cohesive section
>   "looking right" by itself. Then add in the spare wiring or few
>   components separating these "natural divisions" in the schematic. This
>   will often tend to almost magically find distinct functions that are
>   easier to understand, which then "communicate" with each other via
>   relatively easier to understand connections between them.
>
> The above rules aren't hard and fast. But if you struggle to follow them,
> you'll find that it does help a lot.
>
> You can read a snippet of my own education by those schematic draftsmen at Tektronix who trained me by reading [here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/308882/38098)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your schematic is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your circuit is consist of 4 components, so you can draw it in any way. actually it depends upon the other components on the board. So if you have many components on board so you can draw in according to board.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly should know that the breadboard has to be considered as a matrix of rows and columns, where all the insertion's points on each column (on a half-breadboard) are connected together, as in the picture below.

[image]

In this picture, I also added (in red lines) the breadboard's internal connections, so that you can see that your schematic is correct.