# Setting up equations for current, voltage and power analysis of linear electrical net

Tags: basic

The directions of currents are throwing me off a bit.

I think I should use mesh analysis here, but I'm not sure about the exact equation. For example, in the topmost mesh, should I write -120v + 20i1 = 0? I can share the equivalent resistance if needed.

[image]

Comment: but to solve a) you need to know Ohm's law. If you know Ohm's law, and the voltage, and the resistance, you know I_1; so, where is your problem when solving this? Please show everything you've tried. By the way, your question title is pretty much useless: it's there to explain what your question is about *before* someone reads it!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, i guess 120v = I * 20. My problem was that i'm not sure I1 is the current that flows through the resistor.

Comment: no, it's not – how could you solve a) if you have this doubt? Did you actually succeed at solving a)? It's very clearly labeled where I_1 flows, so,  not through the 20 Ω resistor.

Comment: yeah i succeeded at a. R_eq is 10 ohm. oh okay i guess the current is the current of the R_eq since it's passing through the voltage source

Comment: @Rafsan What techniques do you know how to use? Is mesh (KVL) it? Or are you able to use nodal (KCL)? Once you work out (a), then the first half of (b) is handed to you on a silver platter. In any case, which techniques are you comfortable using? Also,. what tools do you use for solving simultaneous equations? (I prefer SymPy, myself.) And finally, have you attempted to redraw and therefore simplify the schematic?

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing I do, before analyzing a schematic, is redraw it (see Appendix below):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKBvuV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is a schematic editor here, by the way. It helps in at least one important way -- labeling parts. This is very important when trying to encourage clarifications before answers can take place.

Verify for yourself that the above schematic is the same as the one you have been given. Note that I picked one node to be "ground." You get to do that for exactly one node. I think you can see which node I chose, and why.

At this point, it should be pretty clear that \$R_9\$ is in parallel to the sum: \$R_7+R_8\$. And that result can be placed in series with \$R_5\$ and \$R_6\$. And that result can be placed in parallel, again now, with \$R_4\$.

The whole thing just collapses into a very simple result.

I've labeled things so that you also should know that \$I_1=I_{1_\text{A}}+I_{1_\text{B}}\$. It should also be clear to you, now, that \$I_{1_\text{A}}=I_{_{\text{R}_2}}=I_{_{\text{R}_3}}\$, that \$I_{_{\text{R}_7}}=I_{_{\text{R}_8}}\$ and that \$I_0=I_{1_\text{A}}-I_{_{\text{R}_7}}\$.

Obviously, (a) is \$\frac{120\:\text{V}}{I_1}=\frac{120\:\text{V}}{I_{1_\text{A}}+I_{1_\text{B}}}=\frac{120\:\text{V}}{I_{1_\text{A}}+\frac{120\:\text{V}}{20\:\Omega}}=\frac{120\:\text{V}}{I_{1_\text{A}}+6\:\text{A}}\$. And you should be able to readily now compute \$I_{1_\text{A}}\$, by simplifying and reducing that part of the schematic.

From there, all the rest follows pretty quickly.

### Redrawing Schematic Appendix

> Get into the practice of redrawing schematics. It will help a lot. Especially, as you get better at it.
>
> Rules to live by are:
>
> - Arrange the schematic so that conventional current appears to flow from the top towards the bottom of the schematic sheet. I like to
>   imagine this as a kind of *curtain* (if you prefer a more static
>   concept) or *waterfall* (if you prefer a more dynamic concept) of
>   charges moving from the top edge down to the bottom edge. This is a
>   kind of flow of energy that doesn't do any useful work by itself, but
>   provides the environment for useful work to get done.
> - Arrange the schematic so that signals of interest flow from the left side of the schematic to the right side. Inputs will then
>   generally be on the left, outputs generally will be on the right.
> - Do not "bus" power around. In short, if a lead of a component goes to ground or some other voltage rail, do not use a wire to connect it
>   to other component leads that also go to the same rail/ground.
>   Instead, simply show a node name like "Vcc" and stop. Busing power
>   around on a schematic is almost guaranteed to make the schematic less
>   understandable, not more. (There are times when professionals need to
>   communicate something unique about a voltage rail bus to other
>   professionals. So there are exceptions at times to this rule. But when
>   trying to understand a confusing schematic, the situation isn't that
>   one and such an argument "by professionals, to professionals" still
>   fails here. So just don't do it.) This one takes a moment to grasp
>   fully. There is a strong tendency to want to show all of the wires
>   that are involved in soldering up a circuit. Resist that tendency. The
>   idea here is that wires needed to *make* a circuit can be distracting.
>   And while they may be needed to make the circuit work, they do NOT
>   help you understand the circuit. In fact, they do the exact opposite.
>   So remove such wires and just show connections to the rails and stop.
> - Try to organize the schematic around ***cohesion***. It is almost always possible to "tease apart" a schematic so that there are
>   ***knots*** of components that are tightly connected, each to another, separated then by only a few wires going to other ***knots***. If you
>   can find these, emphasize them by isolating the *knots* and focusing
>   on drawing each one in some meaningful way, first. Don't even think
>   about the whole schematic. Just focus on getting each cohesive section
>   "looking right" by itself. Then add in the spare wiring or few
>   components separating these "natural divisions" in the schematic. This
>   will often tend to almost magically find distinct functions that are
>   easier to understand, which then "communicate" with each other via
>   relatively easier to understand connections between them.
>
> The above rules aren't hard and fast. But if you struggle to follow them,
> you'll find that it does help a lot.
>
> You can read a snippet of my own education by those schematic draftsmen at Tektronix, those who trained me, by reading [here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/308882/38098)