# What software can I use to draw circuit diagrams like this?

Tags: software

[image]

[image]

[image]

Look at this beautiful circuit simulation, it is in the digital design class document that I received from my teacher.

I want to draw many circuits like that.

What software can I use to draw circuit diagrams like this?

Comment: A circuit *simulation* and a circuit *diagram* are two different things.

Comment: Be aware that those are not schematics - but wiring diagrams. Schematics are used to design, analyse, understand and communicate circuits. Wiring diagrams are used for just what the name sounds like, transferring an existing circuit onto a breadboard without wiring mistakes. When the circuit is no more than a LED and a resistor, it's difficult to see the need for the difference. Once you have 20+ components, a wiring diagram gets to be unusable for design, analysis, communication, understanding. This board has a schematic editor built in, try drawing a schematic version of your wiring diagrams

Comment: ask your teacher

Comment: Looks like Orcad, and not used very well.

Comment: Important: When you say "like this" do you mean "visually and finctionally the same as this" OR "abble to allow me to easily draw schematic diamgrams" or ???

Comment: Kudos for desiring craftsmanship. *Please* apply your artistic intentions to industry-standard schematic diagrams rather than pictorial-type wiring diagrams. Treat schematics as a language - some like Kicad are acceptable. Even with these, you can render a schematic in a cluttered manner, difficult to follow. I've seen auto electrical system schematics that are done in the cluttered manner you intend that would drive an engineer crazy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are any number of programs out there to draw schematics as you show. Many are payware, some are free. From the looks of the horrible resistor, I would venture to guess that this was done in Orcad Capture.

Please don't emulate these diagrams as there things in there which make the schematic harder to read and artistically unbalanced. Some of the icky things are the upside down ground symbol, ground symbol pointing left, non orthogonal wire, 3-2 humped resistor symbol that is stretched out (this was the awful symbol used in Orcad SDT library back in the 1980s and does not fully conform to the symbol used in the IEEE 315 or ANSI Y32.2 standards). Quad gates are generally drawn as separate gates (four individual gates which is a homogeneous part), not all bundled in to a single package since this would create a wiring mess in many circuits.

Please see this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308878/how-were-schematics-drawn-before-cad/308882#308882) for hints on drawing a nice schematic.

Answer (score 7):

Just a note that when you're writing a question or answer here, you can click the button that looks like this: [image]
to draw schematics. I'm certainly not going to claim it's the greatest program possible for the task, but it can produce results that look at least as nice as those you've shown in the question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkvq1v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For what it's worth, it can do actual circuit simulation as well.

When/if you want to use it outside of an question/answer here, you can go to https://www.circuitlab.com/.

Comment: Afraid I can't see how this answers the question *""What software to draw circuit diagrams like this?"* as the schematic tool here is nothing like this. Downvoting for that reason. This could have been a comment, with a link to an example schematic in an existing question or answer.

Comment: @TonyM: In what way do you find it "nothing like this"? There's (perhaps) a rather trivial difference in a provide symbol (showing a gate as a gate, rather than as part of a package), but that's purely a symbol, not anything intrinsic to the software. So, you're obviously free to downvote, but it mostly reflects poorly on you.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I think there are two interpretations. Either, the OP asks in general what kind of different programs there are to draw circuit diagrams, or, which specific program was uses to draw that specific diagram so OP can use the same program. So whether this answers the OPs question depends on what was the intentiom, is the answer simply either "Orcad" or whatever program you want to suggest. But, in the latter case, asking for suggestions what programs to use will be off-topic. So please understand the point of TonyM, you two understand the question differently.

Comment: Actually, OP's question clearly emphasises they want schematics of the shown standard, to draw a lot so must be productive (*"this beautiful circuit simulation", "I want to draw **many circuits like that**", "What software can I use to draw circuit diagrams **like this**?*). Answers I'd expect would be: KiCAD, OrCAD, things of that standard. This answer recommends only what's, compared to those, little more than a sketch tool with a very very low productivity rate (I know, I've used it a lot here). So downvote, and with an (unrequired by site) explanation. Answers must address the question.

Comment: I understand TonyM's perspective and do not disagree with it per se. However, mine is different - I see the OP"s "like this" as open mouthed wonder at the use of new-to-them schemtic drawing software So, +1 from me.

Comment: @TonyM: and yet still a drastic improvement over what he's starting from. To justify something like OrCAD, you need a *lot* more precise specification of how many than just "many". Their idea of "many" may be half a dozen.

Comment: I disagree - I've offered you very consistent explanations and, as said, I actually need give none, users can just downvote. But, unlike the other commenters, you do unfortunately have a personal tone in your comments that's inconsistent with the site's policies, such as the [Be Nice policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: *"and yet still a drastic improvement over what he's starting from"* etc. I'm afraid your comments to me read to me like you're looking for an argument, which the site isn't for and nor am I. I've posted some thorough observations, which is much more than I need to do, and I've nothing more to add.

Comment: I'm not looking for an argument at all, nor have I said anything that suggests anything of the sort. I'm merely pointing out that given his starting point, a tool that's free, and very quick and easy to learn may be far more than adequate. We'd need a lot more detail from the OP to justify a claim that one specific CAD tool is a better choice than another for his (almost completely unknown) purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I take it you're a student. I'm therefore assuming that you probably are operating on limited funds and are not going to pay for commercial software.

KiCAD is free, and it works well for a lot of circuit design tasks. You can generate a conceptual schematic like you have pictured, and then export the list of parts and connections into the PCB design tool. Then you can lay out the physical design of the circuit board and prepare it for fabrication.

I am not an electrical engineer by education or trade, for me it's just a hobby, and I have had a great experience with KiCAD. Some people complain about it, but it is quite capable and you can't beat the price.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [NI Multisim](https://www.ni.com/en-lb/shop/product/multisim.html) 
We used to use it in many courses at university

[image]